# ADB Sideload Password Reset on Samsung Galaxy J3 2016 on Sprint?

Tags: adb, locked-out

### My Problem

A few days ago, I forgot my 3 by 3 pattern password *and* backup pin for my Samsung Galaxy J3 2016 (using the default home and lock screen). I don’t want to factory reset or flash a custom recovery, because I still have my warranty and I don’t want to risk bricking. [One post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66828/what-does-the-command-adb-sideload-file-do) states that in  “Apply Update from ADB”, commands can be executed via a ‘updater-script’ in an update.zip file. Can I use that  to mount enough partitions and access enough commands to follow a password reset tutorial? ([Like this one?](http://joyofandroid.com/how-to-unlock-android-phone/)) Is there a zip ready-made for that purpose?

### Unavailable Options

- The phone runs Marshmallow. No Google-Account unlock.
- Android Device Manager will not replace the current password.
- I do not have a Samsung Account. No using findmymobile.
- I have not enabled ADB normally, when the phone is fully booted.
- ‘ADB devices’ does not show my phone when in recovery unless I use “Apply Update from ADB”.
- I  cannot use ‘fastboot boot’ or any other fastboot command, as Samsung phones only have ODIN Mode.
- I don’t want to use Odin or Heimdall, as they seem to be unstable and risky.
- Kies3 can’t unlock my phone, but it will see it when locked and fully booted.

Comment: You can't expect that - even though ADB sideloading is possible, the zip still has to officially signed, which is of course not the case for anything we create.

Comment: @AndyYan I forgot about that, thanks. I would assume then that only custom recoveries allow me to  flash any zip I want? Know any other ways to reset a password without wipe?

Comment: None I know of - wait for others to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just factory resetting it. Thanks for the information, @AndyYan.